# Expandable Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, expandable

I've got a problem with Expandable Layout (https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2456).
When the app starts, the fragment is inserted in @id(flContent), ExpandableRelativeLayout is collapsed (because of app:ael_expanded="false") and I can expand and collapse this with a click on @id/cerca_button_advanced.
When, with the menu in NavigationView, I load another fragment and then again the first one, the ExpandableRelativeLayout still expanded.
Why does it still expanded, even if app:ael_expanded="false"? I hope someone can help me...

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the fragment.xml inserted in @id/flContent

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cerca_tabella"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:shrinkColumns="1"
                    android:stretchColumns="1">
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_testo_nome"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:labelFor="@+id/cerca_input_nome"
                            android:text="@string/cerca_descrizione_nome"/>
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_input_nome"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences|text"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_testo_via"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:labelFor="@+id/cerca_input_via"
                            android:text="@string/cerca_descrizione_indirizzo"/>
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_input_via"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text|textPostalAddress"/>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_testo_citta"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:labelFor="@+id/cerca_input_citta"
                            android:text="@string/cerca_descrizione_citta"/>
                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_spinner_citta"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                            android:entries="@array/cerca_citta"/>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/cerca_button_advanced"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_button_advance_logo"
                            android:layout_width="14dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/triangolo"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cerca_button_advance_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cerca_button_advance_logo"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cerca_button_advance_logo"
                            android:text="Advanced"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/expandable_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/cerca_button_advanced"
                        app:ael_duration="500"
                        app:ael_expanded="false"
                        app:ael_interpolator="decelerate"
                        app:ael_orientation="vertical">
                        <Switch
                            android:id="@+id/switch1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="New Switch 1"/>
                        <Switch
                            android:id="@+id/switch2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/switch1"
                            android:text="New Switch 2"/>
                    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <my.AdapterLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cerca_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: "I load another fragment and then again the first one, the ExpandableRelativeLayout still expanded" -- if it is the same fragment instance, with the same views, the views would be unaffected. You might wish to explain, in greater detail, what "load another fragment and then again the first one" means.

Comment: In the menu there are some items: when i click on them, a fragment is inserted in @id/flContent. With a click on the first item, the fragment inserted is the one I posted. This fragment is inserted automatically as the app starts.
The problem occurs when i click on another item in the menu (and another fragment is inserted) and then i click again on the first item (the one I posted the code before).

Comment: I solved simplifying the fragent.xml: I removed the first RelativeLayout after TableLayout